# Hierarchy (Tree) Data Model and Query for Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cassandra-3.0

I have to develop an application which stores hierarchy data. What could be the data model in Cassandra and how to fetch the entire hierarchy (similar to MongoDB Graph lookup). e.g.

```
A -> B
B -> C
C -> D
X -> C
```

Expected input/output

```
Input    Output
A        A > B > C >D
X        X > C > D
```

How to achieve this is Cassandra?

Answer (score 3):

Why not take http://janusgraph.org/ & use cassandra as backend?